# codeigniter pagination with join table

Tags: codeigniter, join, pagination, html-table

I'm trying to put pagination into my CodeIgniter project. I've followed the instructions carefully, I did manage to join the table and show them in my "mahasiswa_view", but when I try to combine it with pagination, it says error :

[image: check on this error pic]

Here's my controller code = "home" :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('modelku');
}

function index($offset = NULL)
{
    //pagination
    $limit = 3;
    if(!is_null($offset))
    {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('home/index');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->modelku->total_record_mahasiswa();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    //$data['mahasiswa']=$this->modelku->get_mahasiswa_all();
    $data['mahasiswa'] = $this->modelku->get_mahasiswa_all($limit,$offset);
    $this->load->view('mahasiswa_view',$data);
}
```

And here's my model code = "modelku" :

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Modelku extends CI_Model
{
//pagination
function total_record_mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->db->count_all('tb_mahasiswa','tb_prodi');
    //return $this->db->count_all('tb_mahasiswa');
}


function get_mahasiswa_all($limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->select('tb_mahasiswa.nim, tb_mahasiswa.nama, tb_mahasiswa.tanggal_lahir,
            tb_mahasiswa.jenis_kelamin, tb_mahasiswa.alamat, tb_mahasiswa.propinsi,
            tb_mahasiswa.telepon, tb_mahasiswa.email, tb_mahasiswa.photo,
            tb_mahasiswa.prodi,
            tb_prodi.namaprodi');
    $this->db->from('tb_mahasiswa');
    $this->db->join('tb_prodi','tb_mahasiswa.prodi=tb_prodi.kode');
    //$query = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->order_by('nim','ASC');
    //$query = $this->db->get('tb_mahasiswa','tb_prodi',$limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get($limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

And the last one, my view = 'mahasiswa_view' :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Framework</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>asset/css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Selamat Datang di Form Mahasiswa</h3>

    <table width="80%" border="1" >

        <tr style="background-color:blue; color:white;">
            <td> No. </td>
            <td> NIM </td>
            <td> Nama </td>
            <td> Tanggal Lahir </td>
            <td> Jenis Kelamin </td>
            <td width="20%"> Alamat </td>
            <td> Telepon </td>
            <td> Email </td>
            <td> Prodi </td>    
            <td> Photo </td>
        </tr>


    <?php if(isset($msg_error))
        {
            echo '<div style="color:red;">' . $msg_error.'</div>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        echo anchor('home/login','Login');
        $no=1;
        foreach ($mahasiswa as $row)
        { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->nim . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->nama . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_lahir . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->jenis_kelamin . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->alamat . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->telepon . ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->email . ' '; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row->namaprodi . ' ';?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->photo . ' </br>';?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
        $no++;
        }
    ?>
    &nbsp
    <form action="<?php print site_url();?>/home/cari" method=POST>
        <input type=text name=cari> <input type=submit value="Cari">
    </form>
</table>

    <?php 
        echo "<br /><div>" .$this->pagination->create_links() ."</div>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still new to CodeIgniter so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you run the code?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir: isn't that in the referenced image? It would have been better to directly see it here...

Comment: @Anthon the question was edited as I was typing my comment, thanks for pointing out

Comment: it says i need to have 10 reputation to put image, sorry about that. Any suggestion about my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant use `$query = $this->db->get($limit, $offset);` `$limit, $offset` inside get()

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

use it like this

Comment: :) use codeigniter's active record api http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: what is the use of that $offset?

Comment: 1)"SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20" => 20 is only the limit value this will return u first 20 rows inside the table.2)"SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10" => 20 is limit and 10 is offset now this will return 20 rows after the 10 th row inside the table

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Noel_Yahan is correct. But what exactly your problem isle which says that;

```
Table 'db_kampus.3' does not exist
```

It might be the case that you are using some third party application and the table [db_kampus.3] is missing.

Try to install the missing table and follow the above answer, It should be working.

Comment: I don't know about that man, but i think it's the pagination limit (3). My database name is db_kampus...

Comment: @Mohammad Arif yes 'db_kampus.3' is not exist because Tirta John defined $limit = 3; as in his controller and in get() he parse $limit and it tries to find a table name called 'db_kampus.3' 'db_kampus' is his database name 3 is appending value of $limit :)